# How to load a Multimaterial .dae in three js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to load a model I made with multiple materials, and I want to know how can I access the array of materials. Here my aproach

```
loader.load('./dae/tenis.DAE', function ( collada){
    dae = collada.scene;
    dae.scale.x = dae.scale.y = dae.scale.z = 0.5;

    dae.traverse(function(child){
        if(child instanceof THREE.Mesh)
        {
            var text = textLoader.load('./dae/part1/part1_DIF00000.png');
            child.MultiMaterial.materials[0] = text;
        }
    });

    dae.updateMatrix();
    init();
    animate();
});
```

But it does not work, even I need to load the texture for the materials in separate way, I can't access this after. Some tips?

Answer (score 0):

I can access all the material by name or by id, my approach was wrong.
You can see all material names on the .dae model file.
Here the right way:

```
 dae.traverse(function(child){
    if(child instanceof THREE.Mesh)
    {
        var text = textLoader.load('./dae/part1/part1_DIF00000.png');
        if(child.material.name == "materialName")
        {
          //do something
        }
    }
});
```